# Different results with application and code in ImageJ

Tags: java, imagej

My problem appeared when I tried to run a picture analysis with ImageJ and try to calculate porosity.

I recorded the macros and run the same procedure in java. The results from these two executions are different and I don't know why. Could you help?

I tried to write the code again using [ImageJ API](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/). The two samples I run are shown below:

```
    ImagePlus imp = new ImagePlus();
    imp = IJ.openImage("path_to_image");
    int measurements = Measurements.AREA + Measurements.MEAN +Measurements.STD_DEV +    Measurements.AREA_FRACTION;
    ResultsTable rt = new ResultsTable();
    Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer(imp, measurements, rt);
    IJ.setAutoThreshold(imp, "Default");
    System.out.println(rt.MIN);
```

And with recorded code

```
    imp = IJ.openImage("path_to_image");
    IJ.run("Set Measurements...", "area mean standard modal min median area_fraction limit redirect=None decimal=3");
    IJ.setAutoThreshold(imp, "Default");
    IJ.run(imp, "Measure", "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

- To get measurements from an [`Analyzer`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/plugin/filter/Analyzer.html), you need to run its `measure()` method
- You are printing `rt.MIN` which is a constant used to define the default headings corresponding to the measurements, see the [source code](https://github.com/imagej/imagej1/blob/master/ij/measure/ResultsTable.java#L29-36). Instead, you should use [`ResultsTable#getValueAsDouble(int column, int row)`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/ij/measure/ResultsTable.html#getValueAsDouble%28int,%20int%29) or [`getValue(String column, int row)`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/ij/measure/ResultsTable.html#getValue%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to get your value of interest.
- Apparently you want to measure the minimum value. You should include [`Measurements.MIN_MAX`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/measure/Measurements.html) into your `measurements` variable to do so.

The code that you recorded seems to be Javascript, not ImageJ macro code, so here are some versions of your script that all take the *Blobs* sample image (*File > Open Samples > Blobs (25K)*), set the default threshold and measure the same parameters.

ImageJ1 macro:

```bsh
run("Blobs (25K)");
setAutoThreshold("Default");
run("Set Measurements...", "area mean standard modal min median area_fraction limit redirect=None decimal=3");
run("Measure");
```

Javascript:

```js
importClass(Packages.ij.IJ);

imp = IJ.openImage("http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/images/blobs.gif");
IJ.setAutoThreshold(imp, "Default");
IJ.run("Set Measurements...", "area mean standard modal min median area_fraction limit redirect=None decimal=3");
IJ.run(imp, "Measure", "");
imp.show();
```

Beanshell (which is closest to Java code):

```java
import ij.IJ;

imp = IJ.openImage("http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/images/blobs.gif");
IJ.setAutoThreshold(imp, "Default");
IJ.run("Set Measurements...", "area mean standard modal min median area_fraction limit redirect=None decimal=3");
IJ.run(imp, "Measure", "");
imp.show();
```

If you want to avoid calls to `IJ` and use the lower level ImageJ API, this is how it looks in Beanshell:

```java
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.IJ;
import ij.measure.Measurements;
import ij.measure.ResultsTable;
import ij.plugin.filter.Analyzer;

ImagePlus imp = IJ.openImage("http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/images/blobs.gif");
// IJ.setAutoThreshold(imp, "Default");
imp.getProcessor().setAutoThreshold("Default");

// IJ.run("Set Measurements...", "area mean standard modal min median area_fraction limit redirect=None decimal=3");
int measurements = Measurements.AREA + Measurements.MEAN + Measurements.MIN_MAX + Measurements.STD_DEV + Measurements.MODE + Measurements.MEDIAN + Measurements.AREA_FRACTION + Measurements.LIMIT;

// IJ.run(imp, "Measure", "");
ResultsTable rt = new ResultsTable();
Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer(imp, measurements, rt);
analyzer.measure();

Double result = rt.getValue("Min", rt.getCounter() - 1); // get value of interest
IJ.log(result.toString()); // print to log window
// Alternatively, show the full results table
// rt.show("New Results");
```

Comment: Thank you for you immediate answer. You are totally right about my code. I am new in ImageJ. I tried to find kind of tutorial for the API but I couldn't find anything. Do you know any book or site related to using the ImageJ Api except the official site?

Comment: @raistlin This [tutorial by Werner Bailer](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/docs/pdfs/tutorial12.pdf) might be useful; the best place to ask questions is usually the [ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/list.html); and you'll find more ressources about [plugins](http://fiji.sc/Introduction_into_Developing_Plugins) and [scripting](http://fiji.sc/Category:Scripting) on the Fiji wiki. Since it's a wiki, feel free to add information useful for others who might be in the same situation as you are now.